# One one and continuous function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$

Tags: functions, continuity

Let $f :\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous and one one function. Then which of the following is true?

1. f is onto.
2. f is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.
3. There exist $x \in \Bbb R$ such that $f (x) = 1$
4. f is unbounded

Comment: What do you think? Do you know any examples of functions $f\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that are continuous and one-to-one?

Answer (score 4):

1, 3 and 4 are not true.
The function $f(x) = \tan^{-1}x + 10$ is a counterexample for all of them.

2 is true.
To show this, assume the contrary and derive a contradiction using intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 3):

The function $f$ is not onto; The arctangent function is an example.

2 is true

3 is false.  Shift the arctangent function up.

4 is false.  Again the arctangent function.

Comment: Thanks to all who helped me to converge one option that is correct. Please provide me a proof of option 2.